# Unable to use Integer types in the Request

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc, linq

I am trying to design a credential retrieval process. I tried using `HttpRequestBase`. However, I am unable to move further. `HttpRequestBase` only takes string but, I have to pass int. The database has 'EmailID as string' and 'TaxID as int' Following are the two scenarios I am having trouble with.

Scenario 1:

```
string EmailID = Request["EmailID"];
int TaxID = Request[TaxID];
//Tax ID is having following errors
//Error CS1503: Argument 1: cannot convert from 'int' to 'string'
//Error CS0165: Use of unassigned local variable 'TaxID'
SUPRTestingDBEntities2 dbcontrol = new SUPRTestingDBEntities2();
var userAuth = (from data in dbcontrol.SUPRTesting where data.EmailID == EmailID
                                && data.TaxID == TaxID
                                select data).FirstOrDefault();
if (userAuth != null)
{
    Session["EmailID"] = userAuth.EmailID;
    Session["LoginID"] = userAuth.LoginID;
    return RedirectToAction("LIDAuthentication", "Corporation");
}
else if (userAuth == null)
{
    return View();
}
```

Scenario 2, here I changed `TaxID` type to string (line 2), which throws the error in line 5:

```
string EmailID = Request["EmailID"];
string TaxID = Request[TaxID];
SUPRTestingDBEntities2 dbcontrol = new SUPRTestingDBEntities2();
var userAuth = (from data in dbcontrol.SUPRTesting where data.EmailID == EmailID
                                && data.TaxID == TaxID
                                /*Error CS0019: Operator '==' cannot be applied to operands of type 'int' and 'string'*/
                                select data).FirstOrDefault();
if (userAuth != null)
{
    Session["EmailID"] = userAuth.EmailID;
    Session["LoginID"] = userAuth.LoginID;
    return RedirectToAction("LIDAuthentication", "Corporation");
}
else if (userAuth == null)
{
    return View();
}
```

Can someone help me with this.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

What you need is converting your `TaxId` request to int and then your Scenario 1 should works fine, something like this:

```
int TaxID = Convert.ToInt32(Request[TaxID]);
```

However I would do this to better handle all of the possible errors:

```
string taxID = Request["TaxID"];

if (!String.IsNullOrEmpty(taxID) && int.TryParse(taxID, out int TaxID))
{
    //Your code here, use TaxID in your query
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Unless I've misunderstood what you're trying to do, you shouldn't need to use `Request` at all. You can obtain this information by adding parameters to the controller method:

```
public ActionResult MyMethod(string EmailID, int TaxID) // query string parameters moved to method parameters
{
    SUPRTestingDBEntities2 dbcontrol = new SUPRTestingDBEntities2();
    var userAuth = (from data in dbcontrol.SUPRTesting
                    where data.EmailID == EmailID
                        && data.TaxID == TaxID
                    select data).FirstOrDefault();

    if (userAuth != null)
    {
        Session["EmailID"] = userAuth.EmailID;
        Session["LoginID"] = userAuth.LoginID;
        return RedirectToAction("LIDAuthentication", "Corporation");
    }
    else if (userAuth == null)
    {
        return View();
    }
}
```